# How to delete complete object from heap in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory

Say I have something like this:

```
a = new A(); 
a->b = new B(); 
a->b->c = new C();
```

If I call:

```
delete(a)
```

Would it also delete b and c from memory? How can I be sure that all of them are gone?

This is a question that came up in one of my college classes, made by another student. No more info is given. I guess there is no definitive answer then, because I cannot tell you about the A,B or C destructors

Comment: Depends on what your destructor for each of the classes does.

Comment: It depend, what do ``A``, ``B`` and ``C`` destructor do ?

Comment: Well this is a question that came up for one of my college classes. This is all I have. I found it odd that it had no more info, but I guess that this is just a bad question

Comment: "How can I be sure that all of them are gone?" write C++ code, not C with some C++ syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
class A
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
}
```

You don't need destructor for A or B. Default ones will do.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create destructor for A and B.
2. use smart pointer std::unique_ptr (or std::shared_ptr).

Answer (score 1):

if you have such code in your program:

```
a = new A(); 
a->b = new B(); 
a->b->c = new C();
```

you need to (re)learn how to program in C++ properly. Member `b` of `a` and member `c` of `b` should be initialized by their constructor, not directly. When you write a constructor that use dynamic memory you should immediately think about memory management - either through smart pointers or properly following [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))
After you do that there would be no question if memory would be cleaned properly when `a` is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated, this is not my piece of code. It is a question for one of my classes at college that I did not know answer to.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it also delete b and c from memory?

Only if A's destructor contains code to explicitly do that or if `b` is some kind of smart pointer that takes care of it (and can accept the assignment). E.g.:

```
class A {
  B *b;
  ~A() {
    delete b;
  }
};
```

> How can I be sure that all of them are gone?

Presumably you're asking about best practices for avoiding leaks.

1. Don't use naked `new`/`delete`.
2. The entity responsible for allocating resources should always also be responsible for deallocating them.
3. Use RAII.

Answer (score -1):

Without any info on how the destructors are defined, then it is true that there is no definitive answer. If there are no explicitly defined destructors, then the default destructors are used, and the code would cause memory leaks. If destructors are properly defined for those classes, then yes, `delete(a)` should delete b and c from memory.

So in other words, if something like this is defined in the code:

```
B::~B() { delete c; }
A::~A() { delete b; }
```

then the answer is yes. If not, the answer is no. If you don't know, then the answer is you can't know.

Comment: You assume that `c` and `b` are raw pointers, which is not known.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the lines: `a->b = new B(); ` and `a->b->c = new C();` show that they are pointers.

Comment: That does not change anything, there are many implementations of smart pointers, not only in `std`

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of the question. I just gave an example, I'm not making assumptions. The answer is still the same: "Without any info on how the destructors are defined, then it is true that there is no definitive answer. "

Comment: You also say "if something like this is defined then yes". This is misleading at minimum.

Comment: The word "like" is there for a reason. It was just a simple example, and the point of the example was: "If there is code made to cleanup memory in the classes, then deleting a will also cleanup b and c." That could mean either there are raw pointers being deleting in the destructor, or there are smart pointers being used.